# not realistic simulatoin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to simulate robots using neural networks and genetic algorithms. here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5YpXGuhTsw)  to the video.

I don't know why when the two legs being in the air the cube link don't fall down like it should be in real life. even if I put its mass to 100. The gravity is set as default.

I know that the real time factor can affect, but what are other properties that I have to adjust ?

thank you very much !

here is the SDF file :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
<model name="fourlegs">

  <static>false</static>

  <!--**********************body************************************-->
  <link name='corps'>
      <pose>0 0 .04 0 0 0</pose>

      <inertial>
        <mass>100</mass> 
      </inertial>

      <collision name='collision'>
       <geometry>
        <box>
         <size>.1 .1 .02</size>
        </box>
       </geometry>
     </collision>

     <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
       <box>
         <size>.1 .1 .02</size>
       </box>
      </geometry>             
     </visual>
</link>
<!--*********************left leg *******************************-->
<link name='jambeDG'>
<pose> .06 .04 .01 0 0 0</pose>

<inertial>
  <mass>10</mass> 
</inertial>
<collision name='collision'>
  <geometry>
    <box>
      <size>.02 .02 .06</size>
    </box>
  </geometry>
</collision>

<visual name='visual'>
  <geometry>
    <box>
     <size>.02 .02 .06</size>
    </box>
  </geometry>             
</visual>  
</link>
<!--*********************right leg*******************************-->
 <link name='jambeDD'>
  <pose> -.06 .04 .01 0 0 0</pose>

<inertial>
  <mass>10</mass>
</inertial>

<collision name='collision'>
  <geometry>
    <box>
      <size>.02 .02 .06</size>
    </box>
  </geometry>
</collision>

<visual name='visual'>
  <geometry>
    <box>
      <size>.02 .02 .06</size>
    </box>
  </geometry>             
</visual>
</link>

<!--*************************************************************-->
<!--**********************JOINTS*********************************-->
<!--*************************************************************-->
    
<!--**********************joint left leg************************-->
<joint type="revolute" name="jointJambDG">

<pose> -.01 .0 .03 0 0 0</pose> 

<child>jambeDG</child>
<parent>corps</parent>
<axis>
  <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>
<!--**********************joint right leg************************-->
<joint type="revolute" name="jointJambDD">
 <pose> .01 .0 .03 0 0 0</pose>
 <child>jambeDD</child>
 <parent>corps</parent>
 <axis>
   <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>  
   </axis>
</joint>
</model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7917/not-realistic-simulatoin/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-02-02**:
One thing that could help is setting the inertia matrix for each link. [This tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=inertia&cat=build_robot) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What you are seeing is the dynamics for the default moment inertia (I = identity matrix) when a more physically realistic one is not specified.  My suggestion is to update the models with realistic MOI using equations from [references such as this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) based on object mass, size and density distribution.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2015-03-07**:
Thanks for your answer. I set up the inertia properties like shown in the wiki page. But when I give joints a 0.1 force and 0.1 velocity the robot starts to jump and pounce with a fast way, not realistic at all, I don't know if it's the gravity or ground friction ?! I will try Ricardo Tellez's approach and see...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The key to have realistic simulations is to provide a correct section  ...

A proper section should look like this:

```
<inertia> <!-- interias are tricky to compute -->
      <!-- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4372/the-inertia-matrix-explained/ -->
      <ixx>0.000033719</ixx>       <!-- for a box: ixx = 0.083 * mass * (y*y + z*z) -->
      <ixy>0.0</ixy>         <!-- for a box: ixy = 0 -->
      <ixz>0.0</ixz>         <!-- for a box: ixz = 0 -->
      <iyy>0.001305175</iyy>       <!-- for a box: iyy = 0.083 * mass * (x*x + z*z) -->
      <iyz>0.0</iyz>         <!-- for a box: iyz = 0 -->
      <izz>0.001322294</izz>       <!-- for a box: izz = 0.083 * mass * (x*x + y*y) -->
    </inertia>
  </inertial>
```

Steps to follow:

0- Use Blender to automatically set the center of mass and arrange the axis of the object at that center (this will make later steps easier)
1- Use the tutorial chapulina has suggested to calculate the inertial parameters and set the model. Don't forget to set a correct mass value (the one you have now seems unrealistic)
2- Use Gazebo's option View->Center of mass/Inertia to observe if your inertias are correct (see figures attached for a wrong one an a correct one, for a spoon)
3- If they do not show correct, iterate

INCORRECT INERTIAS
[image: image description]

CORRECT INERTIAS
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Ricardo Tellez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1118/ricardo-tellez/) with karma: 78 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2015-03-07**:
thanks for your answer, I will try that out